# AngularJS - figure out when route change is from manual URL change or from $location.path setting

Tags: angularjs, routes

$routeChangeSuccess broadcast can be seen when there is a routing change, so that you know when the URL changed. The problem is that you don't know if this is a result of the user manually typing in a URL and hitting enter, or from clicking on an href or using $location.path in your application. Is there a way to be able to tell the difference when a routechange is a result of the internal application or from manually entering a URL?

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route, the `$routeChangeSuccess` broadcast has a parameter called `previous` containing information about the previous route.

If the user enters a URL manually, `previous` should be `undefined`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case when the user is already in the application, and then manually navigates elsewhere in the app by changing the URL. E.g. if I am on /app/route/1, and then manually enter /app/route/2 as the URL then previous will be defined.

Comment: I assume you have a `#` in the URL?

Comment: yep, there is a hash in the url, so to be more accurate the user would be going from app.html#/route/1 to app.html#/route/2

Comment: In that case I don't think there's a trivial way AngularJS could distinguish the change of route from `/route/1` to `/route/2` by typing the path after `#` to by clicking a link.

Comment: Is there a way if the path in the app is only set using $location.path, with no hrefs? I assume you would be able to watch for $locationChangeStart, and be able to figure out if the location is set internally, but don't know the specifics.

Comment: Hmmm there's also the `$locationChangeSuccess` broadcast. I've always used AngularJS UI Router so I'm not familiar with it. Have you tried listening to the `$locationChangeSuccess` broadcast?